# How does video encoding bitrate affect duration and why?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, bitrate

Does encoding an uncompressed video into a higher bitrate take longer (than into a lower bitrate)?

If so, why - it seems that the encoder should need less effort because it doesn't have to compress the file so hard?

If no, why - doesn't more quality mean more work for the encoder to do?

I just can't get my head around this.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on a number of things: the codec, the encoding software, how well each was optimised, the speed of your storage and so on? The best way to answer this question would be to do some tests, otherwise you're just speculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lossy encoding is basically compression, achieved through various algorithms. Let's consider the edge cases, and from there, we deduct an answer to your question.

Imagine your input video should be encoded with the best quality. What does that mean, exactly? Well, we just take every pixel as it is, and store it like that. How much time do we need to do that? Almost none. That would be the fastest.

You could then go ahead and try to minimize the differences between frames by only coding their relative differences. You predict frame *B* from frame *A* and then store the residue after subtracting the prediction from *B*. That leaves you with the same quality, but it increases processing time. It also gives you a much smaller file.

What if you want to further decrease file size? Now this is where different quantization and optimization algorithms kick in. You could calculate the amount of spatial and temporal detail in a region of frames and then dynamically adjust the relative quality of that part in the video so it is perceived with a certain level of quality. This is the [CRF mode in x264](http://slhck.info/articles/crf). In that case, if you want high quality, there's not much to be done by the encoder—it doesn't have to "throw away" so much, simply speaking.

Basically, when you tell an encoder that it doesn't have to work as hard in optimizing the quality, it will be faster.

But maybe we should just do a small test. I took a 30 second sample of a movie and encoded it with x264, using various CRF settings on a server. Here's the time needed:

[image]

Same for bitrates:

[image]